# Hash verification error in php

Tags: php, security, hash, password-encryption

I would like to verify my stored hashed passwords with the inputs that the users insert.

What theory says...

After read about the mechanism of password_hash and password_verify, I realized that, theoretically, the string that is inserted will be compared with a hash, which, at least in my case, is stored in the site db.

What is happening to me...

I register my users with password_hash and then to verify the login I use password_verify. If I am good and the code is right, this function should verify the input of the user (even if it's plain text(?) ) with the stored hash.

Let's see the code:

Registration code:

```
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
```

Note: There is more code but I guess that this is the most important part so I decided to paste only this part.

Login code:

```
<?php
//controller! 
    require "../model/backend.php";

    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $dbcom = new dbInteraction;
    $dbcom->admlog($username, $password);
    $dbcom->conclose();

?>
```

Verification code:

```
$this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        //$this->pdo = $pdo;
        //$adm = 1;

        $myquery = 'SELECT username, password, isadmin FROM users WHERE username = :username';// AND password = :password'; 

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($myquery);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        if($user === false){

            die('1Incorrect username / password combination!');
        } else{


        //Compare the passwords.
            $dbpass =  $user['password'];
            echo $dbpass;
            echo '<br>bd<br>input<br>';
            echo $password;
            $validPassword = password_verify($dbpass, $password);
            echo '<br>debug <br>';
            echo 'pre pass:<br>';
            echo $validPassword;

            if($validPassword){

                //Provide the user with a login session.
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['username'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();


                //header('Location: home.php');
                exit;
            }else{

                die('<br>no pass--Incorrect username / password combination!');
            }
    }
```

Do I have some theoretical base problem in my code or it's just bad coded? I'm still trying to realize.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Main problem I see with your code is your params for `password_verify` appear to be the wrong way around. Following that, it should be a plain text password you pass into the first param (as you'd expect from user input), as behind the scenes that will hash the password to compare to the second param.

Comment: I can't believe that I put the params in the way around... After read what I read... Thank you @JonStirling. Btw, is it secure enough? Thanks.

Comment: Is the Password API secure enough? Yes, at the moment. What I'd suggest is looking at the other password api functions, in particular [password_needs_rehash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) and using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`. Using those 2 in conjunction means that if PHP adds a more secure algorithm, your  hash can be updated automatically for you to store.

Comment: Interesting function. I will implement this. Already answered. You can answer the question if you like, @JonStirling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the order of password_verify params.

It should be like  `$validPassword = password_verify($password, $dbpass);` 
or in generic words: 
 `$validPassword = password_verify('String to verify', 'Saved password');`

Special thanks to @JonStirling